# Por que o registro é removido sendo que o owner foi alterado?

Tags: php, doctrine-2

Eu criei um método para alterar o *owner* dos registros.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Contato\Entity\Email t SET t.$column = :contato1 WHERE t.$column = :contato2";
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($sql);
$query->setParameters(array(
    'contato1' => $contato1,
    'contato2' => $contato2
));
$query->execute();
```

Após a *query* ser executada os registros são atualizados fisicamente no banco de dados. Mas quando o comando para excluir o antigo *owner* é executado, os registros que foram atualizados também são excluídos que neste caso exemplificado, os e-mails são excluídos.

```
$this->getEntityManager()->remove($contato2);
```

O que preciso fazer para excluir o `$contato2` sem remover os seus antigos relacionamentos que foram destinados a outro contato?

Comment: Você poderia guardar a query antiga, ou no caso a informação antiga em uma var, cria uma query com essa inf. após isso deleta a antiga informação e adiciona a nova, caso isso não retorne nenhum erro você exclui a variavel que guardou.... isso que  eu entendi do seu problema, ou posso estar muito errado.

Comment: Não é isso não kkk vou atualizar a questão com um exemplo lógico.

Comment: ok, irá facilitar kkkk

Comment: Os dois comandos são executados no mesmo processo ou em processos distintos? Pode ser que o Doctrine está mantendo cache das relações mesmo após fazer flush das alterações.

Comment: Em processos distintos. Primeiramente eu executo 7 funções que realiza o update de forma semelhante ao explicado e no final de toda operação eu executo o `remove()`; Coloquei um `flush()` antes do `remove()` para desencargo de consciência mas não resolveu :'(.